# How to merge and resample two messy datasets with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

I have two drilling datasets with depth ranges and variables that I’d like to resample and merge together.

Dataset 1 has ranges of depth, for example 2m to 3m, with variables for each range. I have taken these ranges and exploded them out to individual intervals using pandas `df.explode`

Dataset 1:

```
Depth_From  Depth_To    Variable_1
0           1           x
2           3           x
4           5           x
```

Becomes this:

```
Depth_Expl  Variable_1
0           x
1           x
2           x
3           x
...
```

The second data set has similar ranges but they are not in depth order like the first dataset, and the depth ranges also overlap in some cases.

I'd like to reorganize these depths from lowest to highest and explode them similarly to the previous dataset. Any variables that overlap due to the overlapping ranges I’d like to just take the mean and have 1 variable result for each single depth interval of 1m. Not sure how to go about this.

Dataset 2:

```
Depth_From  Depth_To    Variable_2
3           6           x
0           2           x
2           3           x
7           8           x
```

Overall I am trying to reshape and merge the two datasets to look like this:

```
Depth_Expl  Variable_1  Variable_2
0           x           x
1           x           x
2           x           x
3           x           x
```

Where each of the datasets are resampled on 1m basis with 1 answer for each variable. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

According to your expecting output, I guess you want to:

1. Collapse the `Depth_From` and `Depth_To` columns into a single column called `Depth_Expl`
2. Combine two dataframes based on the `Depth_Expl` column

If so, you can use `pd.melt()` instead of `pd.explode` and use `pd.merge()` to combine tables.

Try this:

```
# Collapse Depth_From and Depth_To columns
df1 = pd.melt(df1, id_vars = 'Variable_1', var_name = 'col_names', value_name='Depth_Expl').drop(columns=['col_names'])
df2 = pd.melt(df2, id_vars = 'Variable_2', var_name = 'col_names', value_name='Depth_Expl').drop(columns=['col_names'])

# Combine two dataframes
df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Depth_Expl', how='outer').sort_values('Depth_Expl')
```